# Call x function every month in java

Tags: java, scheduler

Each month I would like to run a certain task in Java. However, I don't have access to a cron system or anything outside of the Java environment on this machine.

What would be the most effective way of implementing such system, or does one already exist that someone can provide me with the link to? A solution that I would of would be storing the current time in a file, and then like every day, comparing it to see if the difference is a month and if so then run and reset. But that isn't the most accurate method.

Comment: Does it have to be in Java? And what do you mean by 'reset'?

Comment: Take a look at the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) api, if you have java 8.

Comment: Use a scheduled task (windows) or setup a cron task (linux) or ... @ambigram_maker How is that supposed to solve the scheduling issue?

Comment: @assylias If someone's interested in writing a program from scratch (like I do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a little program and let the operating system handle the monthly execution. Under Windows use the [task scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) or under Linux a [cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: It will be running as a plugin for a server on a shared environment. No access to cronjobs or task schedulers

Answer (score 0):

Several options are available:

1. Do it manually.
2. Set up a cron scheduler.
3. if you insist on pure Java use [Quartz scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Answer (score 0):

## Executor

Modern Java includes the excellent *Executor* framework to easily schedule work to be done on background threads. See [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html). In particular, you want the [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool( 1 ) ;
```

Ask that scheduler to run a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) task after a certain amount of time has passed.

```
scheduler.schedule( runnable , delay , timeUnit ) ;
```

## *java.time*

So next you need to determine the amount of time that needs to pass.

Define your target, the day-of-month. The [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library has a class for that, [`DayOfMonth`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/DayOfMonth.html).

```
DayOfMonth domTarget = DayOfMonth.of( 15 ) ;
```

Get current moment as seen in the time zone by which you want to view the calendar. Keep in mind that for any given moment, **the date varies** around the globe by time zone. The date may be “tomorrow” in Tokyo while “yesterday” in Montréal.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Get the day-of-month of today.

```
DayOfMonth domToday = DayOfMonth.from( now ) ;
```

Extract the current date, just the date, without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate today = now.toLocalDate() ;
```

Compare the day-of-month between today and the target. If today is past the target, move to the next month.

```
LocalDate target = domTarget.atYearMonth( YearMonth.of( today ) ) ; // Get the date for our target day-of-month in the current month (current year-month). 
if( ! target.IsAfter( today ) ) {
    target = target.plusMonths( 1 ) ;  // If target is not after today, move to the next month.
}
```

Get the first moment of the day on the target date. Do not assume the day starts at 00:00. On some dates in some zones, the day may start at another time, such as 01:00.

```
ZonedDateTime start = target.atStartOfDay( z ) ;  // Determine the first moment of the day on that date in that zone.
```

Now we can determine the elapsed time between now and the starting time when we want to run our task. Represent this span-of-time unattached to the timeline as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html). This class internally is a count of whole seconds plus a fractional second.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( now , start ) ;  // Calculate elapsed time.
```

Finally, we can tell our scheduler an amount of time. We specify the granularity using [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum.

```
scheduler.schedule( runnable , d.toSeconds() , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) ;  // Tell our ScheduledExecutorService to run some code after the specified time to wait.
```

Be sure to **gracefully shutdown your executor service** when your app ends, otherwise its threads may survive past your app yet keep running.

Caveat: I wrote this code off the top of my head, untested. So it may not be perfect, but should get you headed in the right direction.